# I am having difficulties when sending testnet ether to my Faucet contract

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I am trying to send goerli ether from my **metamask** wallet to my Faucet Contract and it fails every single time throwing **out of gas** error

I've tried increasing the gas limit and nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

To allow a contract to receive ether you need to add the receive function. The function doesnt need to contain any code, but it needs to exist.

```
contract example{
    receive() external payable {
    }
}
```